# how to get trapezoidal pwm signal

Tags: filter, microcontroller, pwm, motordriver

I generate a PWM signal with a microcontroller Kinetis, I don't want to get really a digital signal what I'm trying to do is to convert this signal to a trapezoidal one where the T rise and T fall are longer.
I've found that I have to set an RC filter than an nmos to get this wave others suggest that no use of the nmos is required ?
can any one help ?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is achievable with digital-to-analog conversion or pulse-width-modulation + rc filter. Not every MCU has a DAC, but PWM can be realized for sure.